# Page with `dynamic = "error"` couldn't be rendered statically because it used `headers`

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

i am use next js in my project , and while i navigate to contact page i find this error attached in photo, i tried to use router or make dynamic reload when i go to this page "because the error is disappear when i reload the page":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng4zD.png)

this is my contact page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmZYr.png)

and this is translation file: "en.json"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YqVQ.png)

I tried several solutions but still have the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the code of the page throwing this error as text?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.